# UIPopoverPresentationController's background broken?

Tags: swift2, ios9

Since iOS 9 I got a problem with the background of the UIPopoverPresentationController. It seems the shape and color are broken.

In the code below I define a popover in the prepareForSegue function and I set its preferred content size and background color. The size is shown correctly but with some mistakes in the shape of the background view. Also the color is not set (the arrow and the broken shape are white instead of dark gray (picture)). In iOS 8 it has worked as expected.

The subclassing of the UIPopoverBackgroundView should be the last option, because I just want to change the color of it, nothing else.

Any ideas?

```
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! StatisticSettings_TVC
            vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 400.0)
            vc.view.backgroundColor = app.COLOR_STAT_LEGEND_BACKGROUND

            if let ppc = vc.popoverPresentationController {
                ppc.delegate = self
                ppc.backgroundColor = app.COLOR_STAT_LEGEND_BACKGROUND
            }
```

[image: Popover bug]

Comment: Same appearance in iOS 9.1 ...